# Android Google Play Service on Emulator - Not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I tried to use the Google Play Service to **display location address** and write code according to the official guide (https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html), but it doesn't work on the emulator. So I downloaded and tried the example code on Github (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationAddress), and still found it not working.

I use the emulator: **Jelly Bean Google APIs (Google Inc.).armeabi-v7a**

Following some solutions on Stackoverflow, I downloaded the Google APIs SDK and Google Play Service SDK with SDK manager, but not working.

Here's the dependency code:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Comment: why don't you use Genymotion simulator which is behave similar like mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

To develop an app using the Google Play services APIs, you need to set up your project with the Google Play services SDK.

If you haven't installed the Google Play services SDK yet, go get it now by following the guide to Adding SDK Packages.

To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:

A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.